# I can't open the url with url_launcher package

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I'm trying to launch a stripe checkout page (in test mode) in the flutter application using `url_launcher` but I get the error:
`PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent {  }, null, null)` , although I added queries to the `Androidmanifest.xml` as described in the package in pub dev website.

```
<queries>
        <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
        <!-- Place inside the <queries> element. -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- Place inside the <queries> element. -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Have you placed it outside `<application>` element?

Comment: @EmanuelLamba Yes. It's directly under the `manifest` opening tag. Is this wrong?